# problem on designing a custom_loss function

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, cnn, loss-function

I am using CNN to solve a regression problem in a supervised manner. i have input data(X_train) and the target data(y_train). I allow the network to train and during training process in each batch of the corresponding epoch

Comment: Hi @simond, unfortunately your post does not give an overall question that you would like help resolving. Can you update this post with the over-arching so the community can best help you.

Comment: Can you add more details so we can help you?